# Remove last n charecters from a string in Ansible

Tags: filter, ansible, formatting, trim, ansible-facts

Below is my playbook that constructs a string.

```
   - name: Construct command for all paths on a particular IP
     set_fact:
       allcmd: "{{ allcmd | default('') + '\"ls -lrt ' + item.path + ' | tail -57 &&' }}"
     loop: "{{ user1[inventory_hostname] }}"

   - debug:
       msg: "allcmd is:{{ allcmd }}"
```

Output:

```
ok: [10.9.9.11] => (item={u'path': u'/tmp/scripts', u'name': u'SCRIPT'}) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "allcmd": "ls -lrt /tmp/scripts | tail -57 &&"
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "name": "SCRIPT",
        "path": "/tmp/scripts"
    }
}
ok: [10.9.9.11] => (item={u'path': u'/tmp/MON', u'name': u'MON'}) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "allcmd": " ls -lrt /tmp/scripts | tail -57 && ls -lrt /tmp/MON | tail -57 &&"
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "name": "MON",
        "path": "/tmp/MON"
    }
}
```

After the loop completes I get the desired string except the fact that I'm left with the trailing `&&` at the end i.e `"allcmd": " ls -lrt /tmp/scripts | tail -57 && ls -lrt /tmp/MON | tail -57 &&"`.

I wish to remove the last 3 charecters i.e `&&` from allcmd variable.  Desired output:

`"allcmd": " ls -lrt /tmp/scripts | tail -57 && ls -lrt /tmp/MON | tail -57"`

Could not find any filters or fuction to remove last n charecters in ansible.

Can you please suggest ?

Comment: You can add the commands to a list (without `&&`) and `join(' && ')` the final list.

Comment: Very elegant solution @Zeitounator. Meanwhile I used `rstrip` filter to get the job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    foo:
      - {"name": "SCRIPT", "path": "/tmp/scripts"}
      - {"name": "MON", "path": "/tmp/MON"}
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: foo

    - set_fact:
        cmds: "{{ [ 'ls -lrt ' + item.path + ' | tail -57' ] + cmds | default([]) }}"
      loop: "{{ foo }}"

    - set_fact:
        allcmd: "{{ cmds | join(' && ')}}"

    - debug:
        var: allcmd
```

output:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "allcmd": "ls -lrt /tmp/MON | tail -57 && ls -lrt /tmp/scripts | tail -57"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

there is a much easier way outlined in this link

http://www.freekb.net/Article?id=2884

```
  debug: 
    msg: "{{ 'Hello World'[:-3] }}"
```

Comment: For me, this is most elegant solution.

Comment: This specific kind of notation is called [Slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/6771046).